# Google Material Icon In a HTML input?

Tags: html, icons

I want an icon to go into an input submit button. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work. Any advice?

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I wanna put the following in:

```
<i class="material-icons">star_rate</i>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways this can be done but according to your code just use

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="material-icons">star_rate</i></button>
```

Comment: This works perfect, I was going to ask how would I add text, but a simple space from the <i> tag did it. Thanks for the help and quick response!